# Gradle WEB-INF/classes folder

Tags: java, jboss, gradle, war

How can I create `WEB-INF/classes` in war when I don't have anyone?
In my war I have only `web.xml`.

I need this because jboss. It cannot deploy project without this folder.

I need `gradle` configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a fake text file to `src/main/resources`, and it will end up in WEB-INF/classes. Explain the purpose of this file by writing it in the file.